# Firefox Sync could not bring my history and bookmarks back

Tags: firefox, firefox-sync

I reinstalled the OS in SSD, and after logging into Firefox, I could not get my passwords, history, and bookmarks. It has been "Syncing..." for some days. Please give me a solution! I still have the earlier installation on my HDD. If copying any file from there can solve this, then please write me the steps to follow.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manually copying the old profile, or its data, is *far* faster; practically instantaneous.

To copy a [Firefox profile](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data#) within the same OS (e.g., Linux -> Linux or Windows -> Windows), just **copy the entire user profile** over. In Linux, you might also need to edit `/home/.mozilla/firefox/profiles.ini` in gedit or Kate to point to the correct profile name. This brings over the whole [kit(fox) and caboodle](https://grammarist.com/idiom/whole-kit-and-caboodle/).

However, I've found that *passwords* on occasion may not be copied correctly between differing OS. In that case, copy the profile, and then bring over data:

[image: Exporting Firefox Profile Data]

- Open the *old* Firefox instance.
- *Export* *Bookmarks* and any remaining *History* from the *Manage Bookmarks* (*library*) dialog.
- [Export saved logins](https://4sysops.com/archives/export-and-import-passwords-in-firefox/) (as plain text CSV!) from *about:logins*.
- Open the new Firefox instance and import that data.

Comment: I moved the whole ".mozilla" directory to the new "/home" directory. Now, the problem is "how to point to the correct profile name?". The "profile.ini" is like [Install<alphaneumeric string>]
Default=<alphaneumeric string1>.default-release
Locked=1

[Profile1]
Name=default
IsRelative=1
Path=<alphaneumeric string2>.default
Default=1

[Profile0]
Name=default-release
IsRelative=1
Path=<alphaneumeric string1>.default-release

[General]
StartWithLastProfile=1
Version=2

Comment: Just replace the old default with the new profile name.

Comment: Got an answer from Firefox community. I pasted the directory of the old installation with the default profile name (check the "profiles.ini" the name is there, it is like a hash code) inside ".mozilla/firefox/common/" beside the current profile directory--> created a new profile by typing "about:profiles" on the address bar and selected the default profile directory of the old installation-->edited the "profiles.ini" of the current installation by replacing the current default profile name with the old default profile name. Now it is working!